# Why is nativeElement undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my parent component, I have a btn and a settings menu directive. What I am trying to do is pass the elementref #navBtn as an input into settings-menu.

```
    <div #navBtn (click)="toggleNav()" class="header__button header__button--left" id="header_button--left">
      <img class="align-absolute" src="assets/imgs/icon_sandwich.svg">
    </div>
    <settings-menu [btn]="navBtn" [navOpened]="navOpened" (navClosed)="navOpened.next(false)"></settings-menu>
...
@ViewChild('navBtn') navBtn: ElementRef;
```

I need this elementref so I can check to see if an event target includes/excludes this element in a HostListener on offclick.

```
  private _btn: ElementRef;
  @Input('navOpened') navOpened: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
  @Input('btn')
  set btn(val: ElementRef) {
    this._btn = val;
  }

  get btn() {
    return this._btn;
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) offClick(e: Event) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('el', this.el.nativeElement, 'btn', this.btn.nativeElement, 'target', e.target);
    if (!this.el.nativeElement.contains(e.target) || this.btn.nativeElement.contains(e.target)) this.closeNav();
  }
```

But this.btn returns the btn html and not an elementRef it seems, because nativeElement on this.btn is always undefined, even in the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the Angular documentation about [template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-):

```
<input #phone placeholder="phone number">

<!-- phone refers to the input element; pass its `value` to an event handler -->
<button (click)="callPhone(phone.value)">Call</button>
```

> In most cases, Angular sets the reference variable's value to the
>   element on which it was declared. In the previous example, phone
>   refers to the phone number  box. The phone button click handler
>   passes the input value to the component's callPhone method.

---

In your code, if you pass `navBtn` as an input value to `settings-menu`:

```
<settings-menu [btn]="navBtn" ...>
```

`btn` will be set to the DOM element referred to by `#navBtn`. You could define the `btn` variable as an HTMLElement in the `settings-menu` component:

```
@Input("btn") btn: HTMLElement;
```

---

On the other hand, if you retrieve the element with `@ViewChild("navBtn")` in its own component, then you get an `ElementRef`, with a `nativeElement` property that points to the DOM element.

Comment: I get that input argument `#phone` is of type `HTMLElement` not `ElementRef`.